Azure logic app - Outlook 365 Get email (v2) InternetmessageId returning 400 Error - The response is not in a JSON format
I am creating an automation that moves emails from junk to the inbox folder in outlook 365. I parse the output of the KQL query into JSON format. Then for each parsed JSON value I assign InternetMessageId to a compose function and set the output to the MessageID and InternetMessageId fields in the Get email (V2) component.
I get the following error when I run the logic app:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "source": "logic-apis-uksouth.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "952bec2d-133a-4d1e-a6dd-c05fc5e6eef5",
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
    "innerError": "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>Runtime Error</title>\r\n        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" />\r\n        <style>\r\n         body {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} \r\n         p {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}\r\n         b {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}\r\n         H1 { font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }\r\n         H2 { font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }\r\n         pre {font-family:\"Consolas\",\"Lucida Console\",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}\r\n         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}\r\n         .version {color: gray;}\r\n         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}\r\n         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }\r\n         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {\r\n          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }\r\n         }\r\n         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {\r\n          pre { width: 280px; }\r\n         }\r\n        </style>\r\n    </head>\r\n\r\n    <body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n\r\n            

Server Error in '/' Application.\r\n\r\n             Runtime Error \r\n\r\n            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">\r\n\r\n             Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.\r\n            \r\n\r\n            Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".\r\n\r\n            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">\r\n               \r\n                  \r\n                      \r\n\r\n<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->\r\n\r\n<configuration>\r\n    <system.web>\r\n        <customErrors mode="Off"/>\r\n    </system.web>\r\n</configuration> \r\n\r\n                  \r\n               \r\n            \r\n\r\n            \r\n\r\n            Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.\r\n\r\n            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">\r\n               \r\n                  \r\n                      \r\n\r\n<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->\r\n\r\n<configuration>\r\n    <system.web>\r\n        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>\r\n    </system.web>\r\n</configuration> \r\n\r\n                  \r\n               \r\n            \r\n\r\n            \r\n\r\n            \r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n"
}
}



Can you share the response you have got from kql query? @David

Which action is throwing error?

If possible please share the logic app code

I have resolved this issue now, I am now using azure graph API calls to get email details, thank you all for your efforts.

You need to verify the below given points to get the expected response.

You can fetch an email only by using Message Id, no need to pass internet message Id separately.

Please note, message Id and internet message Id are different.

Please check if you are passing message Id and internet message Id correctly as I can see you are passing the same value in both the fields.

You need to fetch the message id using KQL query and then parse the kql output. Add a For each loop which takes body('Parse_JSON') as input.

No need to use compose action instead directly pass the message id in Get Email (V2) action in item()['MessageId'] format.

You can also use Get Emails (V3) action to retrieve all the emails from a particular folder and then verify the message id and internet message id.




I have resolved this issue now, I am now using azure graph API calls to get email details, thank you all for your efforts.

You can add the steps which helped you as an answer
